# Angular Test : Access elements of child component from parent

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular7

My Parent Component:
html:

```
<div *ngIf="data.errorMsg.firstName !== 0">
      <child (notes)="saveNote($event)"  [errorType]="data.errorMsg.firstName" nameType="first name"></child>
</div>
```

parent.spec.ts :

```
describe("ParentComponent", () => {
      let component: ParentComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [
            ParentComponent,
            ChildComponent
          ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it("should create", () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

child.html:

```
<div [ngSwitch] = "errorType"> 
  <div *ngSwitchCase = "1">
    SomeError
  </div>
<p #note hidden="true"
</div>
```

child.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: "child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.scss"]
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() errorType: number;
  @Input() nameType: string;
  @ViewChild("note") note: ElementRef;
  @Output() notes: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.notes.emit(this.note.nativeElement.innerText);
  }

}
```

Now, while testing Parent component, I get below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

This happens because rendering of note depends on value of `errorType`. I was getting similar error while testing ChildComponent. But I was able to initialize a dummy value to `errorType`in beforeEach().

But here, it is not possible. How can I initialize the `errortype` variable of child through parent.
OR
is there a better way to test this?

Comment: I would usually prefer the shallow testing approach, and test, that the parent behaves as expected, when the child emits notes and the right property of errorType is passed down instead of testing the child component in a whole again. But if you want to test it that way you would need to mock your data.errorMsg.firstname in your parent test so the errorType is bound correctly. Could you recreate the issue in a stackblitz, than it is easier to show you different solutions.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig To be frank, I have not decided any specific approach here. I understood the second approach you suggested i.e initialize the errorMsg and firstName variable and I have proceeded with it for now. Test case was successfull.
However I am having hard time understanding the first approach - Shallow testing. It's compulsory for me to decalre childComponent else test case fails. Now as it is declared, its code is also executed. How can I test only parent?

Comment: To give you an actual testing example please create a stackblitz with the component you want to test and the test setup you have got so far. Otherwise it's not possible to give you a complete example regarding your exact case. If that's not an option maybe have a look here: [testing nested components](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests)

Answer (score 0):

you should use  `OnChanges` life cycle hook to detect any change in input from parent to child: you can use following code in child component to get latest input element's value:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

        let errorType: SimpleChange = changes.errorType.currentValue;
        console.log(errorType)

    }
```

Comment: Hey @Amrit, right now, I'm not concerned about if everything's working fine. I mean I do, but I don't want to test if the error is rending etc. My motive here is to pass the basic (should create) test.